# How to Produce a Transparent Image with Xelatex

Tags: graphics, xetex, includegraphics, transparency, transparent

I compile the following code with `pdflatex` (which works fine)---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{transparent}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8em,height=11em]{example-image} %\llap{\texttransparent{0.5}{\color{blue!35}\rule{8em}{11em}}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure} [!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8em,height=11em]{example-image}\llap{\texttransparent{0.5}{\color{blue!35}\rule{8em}{11em}}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

producing:

[image]

As one can see, the blue transparency is applied nicely.

However, when I compile the code with `xelatex` (which is the compiler I must use with the actual document), I get the following error messages:

[image]

and (for what it's worth), it produces the following images:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I get this code to compile with `xelatex`; or, how may the code be rewritten so that `xelatex` compiles it?

Comment: Documentation of `transparent.sty`, it was cleared mentioned that this package works on `PDFLaTeX` only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps for you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
%\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8em,height=11em]{example-image} %\llap{\texttransparent{0.5}{\color{blue!35}\rule{8em}{11em}}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure} [!htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=8em,height=11em]{example-image}};
    \filldraw[fill opacity=.5,fill=blue!35] (a.north west) rectangle (a.south east);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```